# How to use CTC Loss Seq2Seq correctly?

Tags: pytorch, nlp, speech-recognition, speech, ctc

I am trying to create ASR model by myself and learn how to use CTC loss.

I test and I see this:

```py
ctc_loss = nn.CTCLoss(blank=95)
```

```
output: tensor([[63,  8,  1, 38, 29, 14, 41, 71, 14, 29, 45, 41, 3]]): torch.Size([1, 13]); output_size: tensor([13])

input1: torch.Size([167, 1, 96]); input1_size: tensor([167])
```

After applying the `argmax` on this input (= prediction of phonems)

```py
torch.argmax(input1, dim=2)
```

I get a series of symbols:

```
tensor([[63, 63, 63, 63, 63, 63, 95, 95, 63, 63, 95, 95,  8,  8,  8, 95,  8, 95,
           8,  8, 95, 95, 95,  1,  1, 95,  1, 95,  1,  1, 95, 95, 38, 95, 95, 38,
          38, 38, 38, 38, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 95, 29, 29, 95, 95, 95, 95,
          95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 14, 95, 14, 95, 95, 95, 95, 14, 95, 14, 41, 41,
          41, 95, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 71, 71, 71, 95, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 95,
          95, 14, 14, 95, 14, 14, 95, 14, 14, 95, 29, 29, 95, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29,
          29, 29, 45, 95, 95, 45, 45, 95, 45, 45, 45, 45, 41, 95, 41, 41, 95, 95,
          95, 41, 41, 41,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3, 95,  3,  3,  3, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95,
          95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95,
          95, 95, 95, 95, 95]])
```

and the following loss values.

```py
ctc_loss(input1, output, input_size, output_size)
# Returns 222.8446
```

With a different input:

```
input2: torch.Size([167, 1, 96]) input2_size: tensor([167])
```

```py
torch.argmax(input2, dim=2)
```

the prediction is just a sequence of blank symbols.

```
tensor([[95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95,
          95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95,
          95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95,
          95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95,
          95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95,
          95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95,
          95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95,
          95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95,
          95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95,
          95, 95, 95, 95, 95]])
```

However, the loss value with the same desired output is much lower.

```py
ctc_loss(input2, output, input_size, output_size)
# Returns 3.7955
```

I don't know why `input1` is better than `input2` but the loss of `input1` is higher than `input2`? Can someone explain that?

Answer (score 2):

The CTC loss does not operate on the argmax predictions but on the entire output distribution. The CTC loss is the sum of the negative log-likelihood of all possible output sequences that produce the desired output. The output symbols might be interleaved with the blank symbols, which leaves exponentially many possibilities. It is, in theory, possible that the sum of the negative log-likelihoods of the correct outputs is low and still the most probable sequence is all blanks.

In practice, this is quite rare, so I guess there might be a problem somewhere else. The [`CTCLoss`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.CTCLoss.html) as implemented in PyTorch requires log probabilities as the input that you get, e.g., by applying the [`log_softmax`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.functional.log_softmax.html#torch.nn.functional.log_softmax) function. Different sorts of input might lead to strange results such the one you observe.